# MSBuild failed with code 1 error

Tags: gulp, visual-studio-2017

I get the following error time to time when I build my project using gulp task runner. It happens randonmnly. If I close visual studio, open a new instance and run the task again it starts working. Does anyone know what is causing this?

Message:
    MSBuild failed with code 1!
Stack:
Error: MSBuild failed with code 1!
    at ChildProcess. (C:\Projects\ProjectName\node_modules\gulp-msbuild\lib\msbuild-runner.js:97:25)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:12)
Process terminated with code 1.

Comment: Were you able to fix this? If you could remember?

Answer (score 0):

Stop the IIS. Run iisreset /stop in admin cmd.

Delete all files and folders under C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files

Start IIS. Run iisreset /start in admin cmd.

Restart Visual studio

Recall if you deleted or renamed any file included in project. If deleted, remove the file reference from csproj file or any other code file where it is being imported or referenced, if the reference still exists. If the file is renamed, see if the file name is reflecting correctly in csproj. Again, if there are any file reference with old name, please remove that reference. Sometimes, Visual studio misbehave if you are dealing with GIT hub with it. So, you need to check this step.

Clean the solution. Build the solution. This might be required if nuget packages download not configured in gulp task.

Again Restart the Visual studio after VS build is successful.

Open task manager (taskmgr) with admin. Go to "Details" tab and delete all msbuild process one by one by right clicking them and selecting end task from context menu.

In task manager, check the RAM & CPU usage if everything is normal. If there is no enough memory available or for some reason CPU usage is high all the time please restart your system or contact your admin if unknown process is eating up your memory or CPU.

If you are using Visual studio 2017, then update Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform to latest version. 
Also, if any unit test project is there for it's respective project, also install  Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform in those project.

Run below commands in cmd with admin access

```
taskkill /IM iisexpress.exe /F
taskkill /im msbuild.exe /f /t
taskkill /im VBCSCompiler.exe /f /t
```

And then try running the gulp task.

Still if error persists, please do checkout the fresh latest copy of your project source code. Then, try to follow above steps once more.